# Site icon is broken on new account confirmation page

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design, login

*My apologies for writing this bug report in English, but while I can (sort of) read Portuguese, I don't write it very well.  If you can, feel free to translate this.*

The site icon shown to users, when they log in here for the first time, is broken:

> [image: Screenshot]

The reason why this happens is that the URL of the image is wrong.  The broken URL is http://cdn.sstatic.net/pt/img/icon-48.png, while the URL that works is http://cdn.sstatic.net/br/img/icon-48.png.

I assume this has something to do with the fact that the URL of this site was changed from the original http://br.stackoverflow.com to http://pt.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Thanks for the report. We can leave it in English, as the devs can't read Portuguese anyway.

Comment: As it is a bug it is probably preferable to be in English.

Comment: Would be nice to revise all URLs that have this `/pt/` and `/br/` structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed next time we deploy (usually a few times each day)

Comment: Thanks! While you're poking in this part of the code, could you also take a look at [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227975/why-does-the-logo-not-show-up-when-signing-up-for-a-site-and-confirming-the-acco)?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen that is ultimately the same thing